# Mobile application want to consume my existing web api in mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, owin

I have an MVC application with web apis. I'm using owin authentication in my app. There web apis work with authorization. the mobile application wants to consume my apis. How can I make consumable these web apis?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a HTML 5 mobile web app?

You can make a jQuery.get() call to the api. This will (AFAIK) use your user's credentials to authorize the api call.

```
<select class="form-control organizationslist" name="organizationslist" 
    id="organizationslist" style="float:left"></select>

var organizationsurl = "/Api/TimesheetActivities";

jQuery.get(organizationsurl, function (data) {
    var organizations = data;
    $("#organizationslist").empty();
    var i;
    for (i in organizations) {
        var organizationid = organizations[i].organizationid;
        var organizationname = organizations[i].organizationname;
        if (organizationid == null) { organizationid = 0; }
        $("#organizationslist").append(
            "<option value='" + organizationid.toString()
        + "'>" + organizationname + "</option>")
    }
});
```